# set text on multiple edit text box if the text is null

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have created some `editText` box in my activity it's like an Update form and all I am trying to do now is to set random value to all the check box whichever is left blank while hitting the submit button. what I am getting is... getting value in only `ETname` `edittext` box and if I am clicking on submit `button` again my app is crashing and even if I am giving any value by myself to `ETname` and submitting it my app is crashing. please help.

public class User_Profile extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

```
private Button Update;
private Context aContext;
private EditText ETname, ETsurname, ETadd, ETpin, ETmail, ETph;

ProgressDialog progressDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_userprofile);

    ETname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_name);
    ETsurname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_sur);
    ETadd = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_add);
    ETpin = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_pn);
    ETmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_mail);
    ETph = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_ph);

    Update = (Button)findViewById(R.id.update_btn);
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

    Update.setOnClickListener(this);

}



@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.update_btn:
            proUpdate();
            break;
    }

}

private void proUpdate(){
    if (ETname.getText().toString().trim().equals("")){
        ETname.setText(SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).getName());
    }
    if (ETsurname.getText().toString().trim().equals("")){
        ETsurname.setText(SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).getSurname());
    }
    if (ETadd.getText().toString().trim().equals("")){
        ETadd.setText(SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).getAddress());
    }
    if (ETpin.getText().toString().trim().equals("")){
        String pin = String.valueOf(SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).getpin());
        ETpin.setText(pin);
    }
    if (ETmail.getText().toString().trim().equals("")){
        ETmail.setText(SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).getUserEmail());
    }
    if (ETph.getText().toString().equals("")){
        ETph.setText(SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).getUserPhone());
    }

        String reg_name = ETname.getText().toString().trim();
        String reg_surname = ETsurname.getText().toString().trim();
        String reg_address = ETadd.getText().toString().trim();
        String reg_pin = ETpin.getText().toString().trim();
        String reg_mail = ETmail.getText().toString().trim();
        String reg_phone = ETph.getText().toString().trim();


        String old_mail = (SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).getUserEmail());
        int reg_id = (SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).getid());

}
```

}

My SharedPrefManager

public class SharedPrefManager {

```
private static SharedPrefManager mInstance;
private static Context mCtx;
private static final String SHARED_PREF_NAME = "mysharedpref12";
private static final String KEY_USERNAME = "username";
private static final String KEY_USER_MAIL = "usermail";
private static final String KEY_USER_ID = "userid";
private static final String KEY_PHONE = "userphone";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "usename";
private static final String KEY_PIN = "pin";
private static final String KEY_SUR = "surname";
private static final String KEY_ADD = "address";

private SharedPrefManager(Context context) {
    mCtx = context;
}

public static synchronized SharedPrefManager getInstance(Context context) {
    if (mInstance == null) {
        mInstance = new SharedPrefManager(context);
    }
    return mInstance;
}

public boolean userLogin(int id, int pin, String phone, String username, String mail, String name, String surname, String address/**, String catagory*/){

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    editor.putInt(KEY_USER_ID, id);
    editor.putInt(KEY_PIN, pin);
    editor.putString(KEY_PHONE, phone);
    editor.putString(KEY_USERNAME, username);
    editor.putString(KEY_USER_MAIL, mail);
    editor.putString(KEY_NAME, name);
    editor.putString(KEY_SUR, surname);
    editor.putString(KEY_ADD, address);
    //editor.putString(KEY_CATA, catagory);

    editor.apply();

    return true;

}

public boolean isLoggedIn(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_USERNAME, null) != null){
        return true;
    }
        return false;
}

public boolean logOut(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.clear();
    editor.apply();
    return true;
}

public int getid(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sharedPreferences.getInt(KEY_USER_ID, Integer.parseInt(null));
}

public int getpin(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sharedPreferences.getInt(KEY_PIN, Integer.parseInt(null));
}

public String getUsername(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_USERNAME, null);
}

public String getUserEmail(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_USER_MAIL, null);
}

public String getUserPhone(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_PHONE, null);
}

public String getName() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_NAME, null);
}

public String getSurname() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_SUR, null);
}

public String getAddress() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_ADD, null);
}

 /**public String getcatagory() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_CATA, null);
}*/
```

}

Comment: have you binded the view with id. Can i see the initialization of ETName ??

Comment: Show your crash report.

Comment: Logcat needed...

Comment: It's an NPE (most common problem), have you double checked the ids of buttons and edittexts and are they in the same layout activity_userprofile.XML?

Comment: it looks like you are messing up with ids in ur xml Or you are picking Id's from wrong xml.

Comment: @LalitSinghFauzdar thanks i've updated my code... now it's setting text in all the empty field but except ETpin I've cross checked my id's please check my [Logcat](https://www.dropbox.com/s/a9tkgz5w8n1i128/LogCat2.txt?dl=0)

Comment: the value you are picking up in PIN is in different format. Re-check it.

Comment: @AkhileshAwasthi is it because it's "int" and not "string"?

Comment: yes. It is the reason.

Comment: @AkhileshAwasthi and how to solve it?

Comment: why are you not using trim() while picking your pin. try using trim() with it too

Comment: @AkhileshAwasthi Updated and tried but still crashing [LogCat](https://www.dropbox.com/s/50khf5clwqwh51y/LogCat3.txt?dl=0)

Comment: Change the data type of pin in your SharedPrefManager to int and return type of getPin() to int as well.

Comment: convert it to a string first `string pin = String.valueOf(SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).getpin());`.

Comment: And one more thing i want to know... is that it's setting text one by one to every field each time i press submit button... but on clicking submit button i want it to check all the field which is empty and set text to all the fields accordingly and then i want to run an update script.

Comment: @SAMEERRAJPAL al your update code seems right...what's the problem then?

Comment: Hi! @LalitSinghFauzdar Everything's working fine thanks for the help... the update user data is working but after updating user data i want it to be updated in My sharedPrefManager also... like i have updated my mail id but in sharedPrefManager it's old stored id. is it possible to refresh sharedPrefManager and and it's stored data to get the latest updated data at the same time? and how to refresh it all the tym i start my app?

Comment: @SameerRajpal You can just call a method to set the new values similar to userLogin Method, just create an instance of SharedPrefManager and Edit those values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the code sample of what I was telling you.

```
      private void proUpdate(){
       ...
        else if (ETpin.getText().toString().equals("")){
           string pin = String.valueOf(SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).getpin());
           ETpin.setText(pin);
        }
       ...
     }
```

For checking and placing text in all edittext at once:

```
private void proUpdate(){
    if (ETname.getText().toString().trim().equals("")){
        ETname.setText(SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).getName());
    } 
    if (ETsurname.getText().toString().trim().equals("")){
        ETsurname.setText(SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).getSurname());
    } 
    if (ETadd.getText().toString().trim().equals("")){
        ETadd.setText(SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).getAddress());
    } 
    if (ETph.getText().toString().equals("")){
        ETph.setText(SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).getUserPhone());
    }  
    if (ETmail.getText().toString().trim().equals("")){
        ETmail.setText(SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).getUserEmail());
    } 
    if (ETpin.getText().toString().equals("")){
        string pin = String.valueOf(SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).getpin());
           ETpin.setText(pin);
    } 
    updateMethodCall(); // your method call
 }
```

This updateMethod will only be called when all the ediitexts are filled and you need not click submit button again.

Comment: I got it Thanks... And one more thing i want to know... is that it's setting text one by one to every field each time i press submit button... but on clicking submit button i want it to check all the field which is empty and set text to all the empty fields at once accordingly and then i want to run an update script.

Comment: Yeah it did... after filling all the empty fields i want it to run update script like if/and { //Update Script using post method from textBox }... how to do it? I am not asking about update script... did you get it? I mean on submit button click it'll fill all the empty boxes and start the updating script.

Comment: What I understood is you want to call a function/method only when all edittexts are filled. Am I right?

Comment: Yes! that's what i am looking for... but i don't want to click on submit button twice.

Comment: Let me try it... I'll tell you if it works fine or gets any error... thanks.

Comment: in my update method I am trying to post some values using EditText Boxes and some values Directly I've updated my code in my question can you please check and tell me if i'm doing it wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Change following methods a bit like this.

```
   public int getid(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sharedPreferences.getInt(KEY_USER_ID, 0);
}

public int getpin(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sharedPreferences.getInt(KEY_PIN,0);
}
```

Comment: And one more thing i want to know... is that it's setting text one by one to every field each time i press submit button... but on clicking submit button i want it to check all the field which is empty and set text to all the fields accordingly and then i want to run an update script.